# Knex.js Error parseLengthCodedNumber: JS precision range exceeded, number is >= 53 bit: "18446744073709551615"

Tags: express, knex.js, mariadb-10.3

I am trying to insert a few rows to a table from an express.js controller, using knex.js:

```
yield knex.withSchema(MySchema).insert(something).into('MyTable');
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: parseLengthCodedNumber: JS precision range exceeded, number is >= 53 bit: "18446744073709551615"
```

The 'something' varible is a set of rows from another table, which have negative ids:

```
'-2', '552', 'something1', NULL, '-2', '1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2020-03-31 14:27:32'
'-1', '552', 'something2', NULL, '-1', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

My database is MariaDB 10.3.21 and I'm using knex 0.12.9

Any ideas?

Comment: check from stacktrace where that `Error: parseLengthCodedNumber: ` error is coming and which knex dialect are you using?. Also please tell what is that variable `something` in javascript object format. That list of strings / values is not enough information. I'm sure it is not just flat array of strings and nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in MySQL `.increments()` will default to `unsigned`. I haven't tested it, but I expect attempting to insert a negative integer will result in an overflow (see [MySQL integer overflow](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html) for exact behaviour). This appears to be resulting in a positive integer that is greater than JavaScript's [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

If you absolutely must have negative IDs, you could probably work around it by setting the table to use signed integers as primary keys, importing the data, then setting the autoincrement starting value to something greater than the highest id represented in the data. I imagine all of your tables would need signed integers as IDs so you're comparing like with like.